# useLazyQuery in Promise.all only storing last response in cache

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to use the same query with different variables using `useLazyQuery`. I built a hook for this reason and it fetches everything alright. However, it never really uses cached data. I looked into the cache and it's only storing the response from the last request in the array. This is a simplified version of my hook:

```
const useProductSearchQuery = (categories) => {
  const [getProducts] = useLazyQuery(QUERY);
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getProducts() {
      const responses = await Promise.all(
        categories.children.map((cat) =>
          getProducts({ variables: { category: cat.id } })
        )
      );
      setData(responses);
    }

    getProducts();
  }, [productCategories, getProducts]);

  return { data };
};
```

I'm not sure if this use case fits `useLazyQuery` so maybe that's why it doesn't work. I just needed an imperative way of running my queries and this seemed easier than using a consumer to pass the client around.

The other alternative would be to just iterate categories and then have a `useQuery` hook for each but I'd prefer having my data ready in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I didn't notice the hooks docs mention the `useApolloClient` hook (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#useapolloclient)... Works like a charm!